# Como criar uma matriz dinâmica usando lista encadeada na linguagem C?

Tags: c

Por favor me ajudem com o que poder sobre o assunto, estou tendo dificuldades com estrutura de dados na faculdade. Desde já agradeço.

O que eu já tenho de codificação!

```
typedef struct tipoElemento {

  int valor;
  struct tipoElemento *abaixo;
  struct tipoElemento *direita;

}TElemento;


typedef struct tipoMatriz {

  struct tipoElemento *inicio;
  int linhas;
  int colunas;

}TMatriz;


TMatriz L;

void inicializaLista(TMatriz *matriz) {

  matriz->inicio = NULL;
  matriz->colunas = 0;
  matriz->linhas = 0;
}
```

Comment: Usando ponteiros para a linha seguinte ou com ponteiros para os 4 elementos consecutivos. Onde você parou ao tentar resolver esse problema?

Comment: Sua definição de matriz está bem segura. Só acho estranho só poder operar indo para a direita e para baixo, mas é plausível de todo modo

Comment: Mas o que não está conseguindo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma implementação capaz de solucionar o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct elemento_s elemento_t;
typedef struct matriz_s matriz_t;


struct elemento_s
{
    int valor;
    elemento_t * abaixo;
    elemento_t * direita;
};


struct matriz_s
{
    elemento_t * inicio;
    int linhas;
    int colunas;
};


matriz_t * matriz_criar( int linhas, int colunas )
{
    int l = 0;
    int c = 0;
    elemento_t * esq = NULL;
    elemento_t * prim = NULL;
    elemento_t * ant = NULL;
    elemento_t * inicio = NULL;

    for( l = 0; l < linhas; l++ )
    {
        esq = NULL;

        for( c = 0; c < colunas; c++ )
        {
            elemento_t * el = (elemento_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(elemento_t) );

            el->valor = 0;

            if( !inicio )
                inicio = el;

            if( esq )
                esq->direita = el;

            esq = el;

            if( ant )
            {
                int i = 0;
                elemento_t * aux = ant;

                for( i = 0; i < c; i++ )
                    aux = aux->direita;

                aux->abaixo = el;
            }

            if( c == 0 )
                prim = el;
        }

        ant = prim;
    }

    matriz_t * m = (matriz_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(matriz_t) );

    m->inicio = inicio;
    m->colunas = colunas;
    m->linhas = linhas;

    return m;
}


void matriz_destruir( matriz_t * m )
{
    elemento_t * ec = m->inicio;
    elemento_t * el = NULL;
    elemento_t * aux = NULL;

    while( ec )
    {
        el = ec->direita;

        while(el)
        {
            aux = el->direita;
            free(el);
            el = aux;
        }

        aux = ec->abaixo;
        free(ec);
        ec = aux;
    }

    free(m);
}


elemento_t * matriz_obter_elemento( matriz_t * m, int col, int linha )
{
    int i = 0;
    elemento_t * e = m->inicio;

    for( i = 0; i < linha; i++ )
        e = e->abaixo;

    for( i = 0; i < col; i++ )
        e = e->direita;

    return e;
}


void matriz_setar_elemento( matriz_t * m, int col, int linha, int valor )
{
    elemento_t * e = matriz_obter_elemento( m, col, linha );
    e->valor = valor;
}


void matriz_debug( matriz_t * m )
{
    int l = 0;
    int c = 0;

    printf("matriz=%p, colunas=%d, linhas=%d, inicio=%p\n", m, m->colunas, m->linhas, m->inicio );

    for( l = 0; l < m->linhas; l++ )
    {
        for( c = 0; c < m->colunas; c++ )
        {
            elemento_t * e = matriz_obter_elemento( m, c, l );
            printf("    col=%d, linha=%d, elemento=%p, abaixo=%p, direita=%p, valor=%d\n", c, l, e, e->abaixo, e->direita, e->valor );
        }
    }

}

int main( void )
{
    int qtd_linhas = 3;
    int qtd_colunas = 5;

    /* Criando Matriz */
    matriz_t * m = matriz_criar( qtd_linhas, qtd_colunas );

    /* Preenchendo Elementos da Linha 0 */
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 0, 0, 10 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 1, 0, 20 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 2, 0, 30 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 3, 0, 40 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 4, 0, 50 );

    /* Preenchendo Elementos da Linha 1 */
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 0, 1, 60 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 1, 1, 70 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 2, 1, 80 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 3, 1, 90 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 4, 1, 100 );

    /* Preenchendo Elementos da Linha 2 */
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 0, 2, 110 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 1, 2, 120 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 2, 2, 130 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 3, 2, 140 );
    matriz_setar_elemento( m, 4, 2, 150 );

    /* Debug da Matriz */
    matriz_debug(m);

    /* Destruindo Matriz */
    matriz_destruir(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ ./matriz
matriz=0xef11f0, colunas=5, linhas=3, inicio=0xef1010
    col=0, linha=0, elemento=0xef1010, abaixo=0xef10b0, direita=0xef1030, valor=10
    col=1, linha=0, elemento=0xef1030, abaixo=0xef10d0, direita=0xef1050, valor=20
    col=2, linha=0, elemento=0xef1050, abaixo=0xef10f0, direita=0xef1070, valor=30
    col=3, linha=0, elemento=0xef1070, abaixo=0xef1110, direita=0xef1090, valor=40
    col=4, linha=0, elemento=0xef1090, abaixo=0xef1130, direita=(nil), valor=50
    col=0, linha=1, elemento=0xef10b0, abaixo=0xef1150, direita=0xef10d0, valor=60
    col=1, linha=1, elemento=0xef10d0, abaixo=0xef1170, direita=0xef10f0, valor=70
    col=2, linha=1, elemento=0xef10f0, abaixo=0xef1190, direita=0xef1110, valor=80
    col=3, linha=1, elemento=0xef1110, abaixo=0xef11b0, direita=0xef1130, valor=90
    col=4, linha=1, elemento=0xef1130, abaixo=0xef11d0, direita=(nil), valor=100
    col=0, linha=2, elemento=0xef1150, abaixo=(nil), direita=0xef1170, valor=110
    col=1, linha=2, elemento=0xef1170, abaixo=(nil), direita=0xef1190, valor=120
    col=2, linha=2, elemento=0xef1190, abaixo=(nil), direita=0xef11b0, valor=130
    col=3, linha=2, elemento=0xef11b0, abaixo=(nil), direita=0xef11d0, valor=140
    col=4, linha=2, elemento=0xef11d0, abaixo=(nil), direita=(nil), valor=150
```